# How do I use sphinx-intl if I am using the .. csv-table:: directives for my tables?

Tags: internationalization, python-sphinx, restructuredtext

My team uses .rst/sphinx for tech doc. We've decided to do tables in csv files, using the .. csv-table:: directive. We are beginning to using sphinx-intl module for translation. Everything seems to work fine, except that I don't see any our tables int he extracted .po files. Has anyone had this experience? What are best practices for doing csv tables and using sphinx-intl?

Comment: This is probably not supported in `sphinx-intl`, based on the assumption that it is similar to another issue, [How do you deal with image internationalization?](https://github.com/sphinx-doc/sphinx-intl/issues/13). You should contact the author.

Answer (score 1):

We tested and verified that the csv content is automatically extracted into PO files, and building a localized version places the translated strings in MO files back into the table.